# Log4j prevent EJB to be created on the glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, glassfish

I have created an EJB project, and it's working fine, but when I add the Logger

```
private transient static final Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(MyServiceDAO.class);
```

for log4j I get an error. That error is :

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB.
```

When I remove the line everything is normal and works fine.

the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session into class com.silence.session.stateless.AttachmentServiceSession: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session into class com.silence.session.stateless.AttachmentServiceSession: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 98 more

2014-03-24T12:41:43.683+0300|SEVERE: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy397.uploadAttachment(Unknown Source)
    at com.ClientBB.init(ClientBB.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider$2.run(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:382)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:376)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session into class com.silence.session.stateless.AttachmentServiceSession: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServic
2014-03-24T12:41:43.683+0300|SEVERE: eImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session into class com.silence.session.stateless.AttachmentServiceSession: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=LookupDAO,Remote 3.x interface =com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO#com.jpa.dao.LookupDAO not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 98 more
```

the LookupDAO class contains :

```
public class LookupDAO extends SilenceServiceDAO<Lookup>{ 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3099010943225418931L;
  private transient static final Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(SilenceServiceDAO.class);
  private UserTransaction transaction; 

  ....
}
```

Comment: Show us the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: it's too long and messy :)

Comment: The error log says "Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/LookupDAO'.." try to investigate around this. Do you have such bean deployed ? Browse in the JNDI tree and see.

Comment: thanks, when i remove the line, my application back working fine, this line inside the LookupDAO class

Comment: There is no mention anywhere of log4j - are you sure your project gets compiled properly when you add log4j?  Also, are you sure log4j gets packaged with the project?

Comment: @Hazim stacktraces tend to be long and messy, but very useful. :)

Comment: public class LookupDAO extends SilenceServiceDAO<Lookup>{
 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 3099010943225418931L;
 
 private transient static final Logger LOG=Logger.getLogger(SilenceServiceDAO.class);
 private UserTransaction transaction;